# Use of str() in print()

Tags: python

If I use:

```
>>> n = input("What is your name? ")
What is your name? 23

>>> print("Hello " + n)
```

The Output is

`Hello 23`

Then it prints correctly. But if I use:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> print("Hello" + n)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in
<module>
    print("Hello" + n) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Then it gives an error.
I know that it is not allowed to print numbers with string without using the `str()` function, so in the first case why does it not give an error?

Comment: cannot concatenate two different types together, you should use print("Hello"+str(n))

Comment: Because in the first case, *both* `"Hello "` and `n` are *strings*, in the second case, `"Hello "` is a string, but `n` is an `int`. `print` doesn't matter, and actually `print` will automatically call `str` on any of its arguments. the problem is the `+`

Comment: If you want to see it for yourself. Try `type(n)` as it would return a <class 'str'>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `input()` **always** returns a `str`.

In your first example, `n` is `"23"`, not `23`, so the concatenation works.

Answer (score 3):

The `input` function always returns a string, so even if the user inputs a number, `input` still returns the number in a string, and therefore it can be concatenated with another string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `input()` returns a string, i.e., in your example, the string `'23'`.

Check:

```
>>> n = input("What is your name? ")
What is your name? 23

>>> print(type(n))
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The action of operator `+` depends on the type of operands, but both need to be of same `type`. For strings, it is meant for concatenations, and hence both the operands are expected of same type `string`. However, `python` still lets you print two different type of operands on same line using `,`.

For example,

`print("Hello ",n)`

Comment: `+` is not meant for concatenation in the way you suggest. It just depends on the operands, so while your answer will work, your statement is not correct. You also don't need to add the whitespace to the end of your string in this case.